# value of $_POST is always the last value of my <tr>

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a problem in which I cannot solve. I have a simple page where I query all Users and list them in a table. When a user clicks on one of the table rows, it should be taken to another page where the user can edit information of the  that they picked. The problem is that in my script, the $_POST value is always the value of the last

CODE

```
    <?php
    include "conn.php";
    $pquery = "SELECT * FROM Patient NATURAL JOIN User ORDER BY LastName;";
    $patientQuery = $conn->query($pquery);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($patientQuery) == 0)
        echo "<p>No patients found.</p>";

    else{
        while($assoc = $patientQuery->fetch_assoc()){

            echo "<tr onclick = 'sub();'>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $assoc['UserID'];
            echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'UserID' value = '". $assoc['UserID'] ."' />";
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            echo $assoc['FirstName'];
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            echo $assoc['LastName'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        }
    }
?>
<script>
    function sub(){
        document.getElementById("edit").submit();
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you're using the same `name = 'UserID'` for every table row, so it's only logical you are always getting the last one sent.

Comment: Right, that is the problem. But how would I solve this problem to get the result that I need?

Comment: Maybe if I use radio buttons that are hidden which have the same name will work?

Comment: would you consider asking that same question at http://es.stackoverflow.com? It would probably get more attention

Comment: Haha oh my bad, is my English that bad? I'll fix my sentences.

Comment: use `name='UsersIDs[]'` and then check `$_POST` on the next page to see what you get.

Comment: You english is flawless. It's just that I tried writing a decent answer in english and the language barrier kept me from doing it. I could try, nonetheless.

Comment: Oh you speak Spanish? Go ahead and write your solution in Spanish. I speak Spanish too!

Comment: Hi castis, I will try this solution. I've never done that before.

Comment: castis, how would the PHP know the correct index of which the user picked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've slightly modified your code - this should work:

```
<?php
    include "conn.php";
    $pquery = "SELECT * FROM Patient NATURAL JOIN User ORDER BY LastName;";
    $patientQuery = $conn->query($pquery);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($patientQuery) == 0)
        echo "<p>No patients found.</p>";

    else{
        while($assoc = $patientQuery->fetch_assoc()){

            echo "<tr onclick = 'sub(". $assoc['UserID'] .");'>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $assoc['UserID'];
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            echo $assoc['FirstName'];
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            echo $assoc['LastName'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        }
    }
?>

<script>
    function sub(UserID){
        document.location.href = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/something.php?UserID='+UserID;
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I've never passed a variable through the url. How does this work after I send it to the correct page to process? how to I grab the data?

Comment: Same way as before, except you get it from `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: Wow! this is so cool! Thank you for your help. this solution is great!